# Access $hidden attribute inside retrieved event

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I need to modify the `$hidden` attribute of eloquent models inside the `retrieved` event which is a static function, and the `$hidden` attribute is not a static attribute. Any help with that, What I'm trying to do is hide some attributes in run time?

```
public function makeHidden($attributes)
    {
        $this->hidden = array_merge($this->hidden, (array) $attributes);

        return $this;
    }


    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        $user = JWTAuth::authenticate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        if ($user === false) {
            $user = Channel::authInfo();
            $user->type = 'channel';
        }

        static::retrieved(function($model) use ($user) {
            $this->makeHidden($this->toBeHidden[$user->type]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: please provide some code like for `retrieved event` of yours

Comment: @Learner I updated the post and added the code